# How to get the asymptotic expression of DOS near Van Hove singularity

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, asymptotics, density-of-states

1. For the simplest example, 2D square lattice tight binding model gives the energy band as
   $$\varepsilon_k=-2t(\cos k_x+\cos k_y) \, .$$
   We know that $\vec{k}=(0,\pi)$ and related momentum points are saddle points which give $|\nabla_k \varepsilon_k|=0$ and thus some kind of singularity in density of state (DOS) since
   $$\rho(\varepsilon)\propto \int_{\varepsilon=\text{const}} \frac{d S}{|\nabla_k \varepsilon_k|} \, .$$
   How can I get the $\ln$ divergence for DOS near $\varepsilon=0$? Should I only care about those singularity points and omit the integral from normal parts and do Taylor expansion near those saddle points? Why are points like $(\pi/2,-\pi/2)$ not called Van Hove points when those points are also lie in the $\varepsilon=0$ line and give $|\nabla_k \varepsilon_k|=0$?
2. Consider a dispersion relation in 1D like
   $$\varepsilon_k = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
   0 & |k| \le 1 \\
   |k|-1 & |k| > 1 \, .
   \end{array}
   \right.$$
   What kind of divergence near $\epsilon=0$? It seems that the DOS for all $\varepsilon>0$ is a constant and suddenly goes to infinity when $\varepsilon$ is fine tuning to zero.
3. Since there is an integral on the constant energy surface in the DOS formula, what if the constant energy surface is not closed and thus an infinite one? As another 2D  example,
   $$\varepsilon_k=v_xk_x+v_yk_y \, .$$
   The isoenergy surface will be plane extended to infinite and thus ill-defined in the integral $\int dS$. 
   Some one may argue that this kind of Hamiltonian must come from effective theory which is only valid for low energy and thus has a valid region beyond which the dispersion relation doesn't work. Well, if I only care about the divergent behavior and don't want to go further to the 'real' dispersion which is  hard to manipulate (perhaps no analytical expression at all). Can I get the divergent information only from the linear dispersion? Should I give $k$ region a cut off or do something else?

Comment: Any time you find yourself enumerating multiple questions that should tell you that the post is not focused enough. There are three questions in just item #1! Please break this up into separate posts, each one asking a single focused question.

Comment: Yeah...But I think those questions are all related and give a whole picture about what I wanna convey. Of course one can focus on or answer only part of the question. That's why I list those questions in different items.

Comment: I think you may not yet understand how this site works. The goal of this site is to generate a useful set of information in physics. It is *not* just to solve the problem of the person asking the question. To achieve this goal we uphold a somewhat specific set of expectations. These are detailed in the [help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help). One of the most important factors is that questions should be *answerable*. This is incompatible with your notion that someone might address only part of your question.

Comment: Not only does asking focused questions make the resulting question/answer pair more useful, but keeping your questions focused will also get you better answers.

Comment: @Simon.Z Even if the questions are related, it's still best to post them separately. In each question you can add links to the other parts, or just to the previous part, if you prefer. (These are good questions and I would probably upvote all three of them if they were posted separately.)

Comment: I made several new posts according to your suggestion.

Comment: @DavidZ wouldn't such upvoting pattern look like serial upvoting to the bot? ;)

Comment: @Ruslan I can't imagine it would catch on to three posts.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of the new question asking about the first part, because I can't pick more than one duplicate.